# Passing textbox value in href

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, hyperlink

I have the following code and would like to pass `qty1[]` to the hyperlink below which I marked as XXXXXXX.

Can someone help me with this?

```
<td><img src="<?php echo $item["image"]; ?>" class="cart-item-image" /><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item["code"]; ?></td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> <input type = 'text' id = "qty1[]" name = "qty1[]" value = '<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>' /></td>
<td  style="text-align:right;"><?php echo "$ ".$item["price"]; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:right;"><?php echo "$ ". number_format($item_price,2); ?></td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="cart.php?action=remove&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction"><img src="icon-delete.png" alt="Remove Item" /></a></td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="cart.php?action=update&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>&quantity= XXXXXXXXX" class="btnRemoveAction"><img src="icon-delete.png" alt="Update Item" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why not just replace the XXXXXX with the string `qty1[]`?  I'm guessing there's more to the problem than you initially wrote.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement a form without using a form, so the very short version of the answer is "use a form." There is nothing preventing form fields from being in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the quantity change when it happens and update that link's href attribute accordingly. This testable snippet removes all your PHP code (just for testing purposes) but the javascript can be added directly to your PHP page and will work.

One thing, you should initialize that link href in case the quantity isn't changed

```
<a href="cart.php?action=update&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>&quantity=<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>"
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="qty1[]"]').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      let a = e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('a.btnRemoveAction');
      let url = a.getAttribute('href').split("?");
      let params = new URLSearchParams(url[1]);
      params.set('quantity', e.target.value)
      params = params.toString()
      url = `${url[0]}?${params}`;
      console.log(url)
      a.setAttribute('href', url);
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img" class="cart-item-image" /> name</td>
    <td>code </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"> <input type='text' id="qty1[]" name="qty1[]" value='10' /></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"> $3.99</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"> $3.99</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <a href="cart.php?action=remove&code=code" class="btnRemoveAction"><img src="icon-delete.png" alt="Remove Item" /></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <a href="cart.php?action=update&code=code&quantity=1" class="btnRemoveAction"><img src="icon-delete.png" alt="Update Item" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried your code but some how my output is not replicating like snippets output.

Comment: I just updated the answer to wait until page loads before executing. Should work. Pls try, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much now its working correctly. Highly grateful for your help. :)

Comment: @Santosh  - great! Glad I could help. Cheers